# How to use World Map in SSRS 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am a SSRS report Developer and come across the request from user where i can show data in Map like number of Count or average for something. but i don't know anything about MAPs in SSRS. and i have checked and found there is no World MAP in SSRS. if any one have a solution for my problem please help. I want to learn from scratch.

Thanks and Regard,
Dilip Chauhan

Comment: Dilip you are astoundingly lazy.  Try googling SSRS world map - there is so much info available.

Comment: @MikeHoney thanks for your comment but i already did that and found nothing . If you have any link or any reference to website please share with me. Thanks & regards dilip chauhan

Comment: You've just proved my first point.  Good luck!

Comment: Lol thanks well i am trying and will come with something good. Sure. Anyway thanks for your comment.